# Should mailed ballots that are received AFTER deadlines be counted? (US)

Tags: united-states, election, voting, vote-by-mail

I believe that all US states have statutory requirements for election ballots for to be submitted in a timely fashion to be eligible to be counted. These statutory requirements are published and available to the electorate well in advance of an election.

If a voter chooses to ignore those requirements, are there any plausible arguments that their mailed vote should be counted as an eligible vote.

(This question is predicated on the notion that voters are provided ample opportunity to mail their ballot well in advance deadlines. Similarly, applications to receive a absentee ballot allow plenty of time in advance of an impending election)

**ETA: Please offer comments to explain why this question is not about government processes or why it's perceived to be in bad faith and/or intended to promote or discredit any political cause, group or politician**

Comment: In practical terms, how do you differentiate between a voter who "chooses to ignore the requirements" and a voter who is unaware of the requirements?

Comment: The requirements (regarding receipt by a BOE)  are published, and even if a voter were oblivious to the published, voters intuitively "know" that their ballots need to be at the BOE  on or about election day. If the voter elects to wait till the last minute to send a ballot, versus sending that same ballot a week or two (or more) that is taking the risk that the ballot will arrive late. To my mind that risk should be at the jeopardy of the voter.  Liken this to the person who **waits** for the football game to begin to purchase a ticket, there is a risk (by waiting) that no tickets available.

Comment: Hpw is this different from an in-person voter who shows up at the polling place after it closes?

Comment: @jamesqf When the voter didn't plan for the usual commute time plus some safety, that's their fault. Same for mailing in a vote too close to the deadline. But if a political actor were to sabotage public transportation and streets on election day so that it takes a highly unusual amount of time to get to the poling station, I think it would be unfair to blame voters for not arriving in time. The same would be true for purposefully sabotaging the USPS to manipulate an election.

Comment: @tim it's not a matter of blaming voters, and in fact judges do extend voting hours due to unusual events that are unforeseen. However, the coronavirus fears are clearly not unforeseen and now that states and the public has been warned about  postal delays the prudent voter would be sure to allow extra time.

Comment: @jamesqf IMO it's not different. If I show up at my polling place at .10PM on election day and the polls closed at 8PM in accordance with the state laws, I would expect that I will not be permitted to vote. I suppose that I could file a (nuisance) lawsuit, but barring highly unusual and unpredictable circumstances (terrorist attack by Somali pirates), a magistrate would dismiss in a New York minute.

Comment: ATTN MODERATOR: Request reopening: At this time there have been no comments offered to improve this question. At this time there have been no comments that claimed the question was off-topic. At this time there have been no comments that allege that question is posed to support or discredit a political cause, group or politician. There have been no comments that the question is not in good faith  where good faith means that you're not solely playing (or pandering) to an audience.

Comment: I didn't participate in the process, but it looks to me that you are asking for an opinion. I know that's not the reason for the closure, but you're not asking what politicians think about this, but rather what we think about the topic.

Comment: @gktscrk the question asked for any plausible arguments, without regard to source (be it SE participants or politicians. Actually I have found a (rather dated) politician arguing that  technical arguments (such as failure to properly date the submission of a ballot) should not be used to invalidate  an absentee ballot ( Liberman on CNN ) [ https://www.cnn.com/2015/11/02/politics/bush-gore-military-ballots/index.html ]. His justification was "it's not consistant or right" to look to the letter of the law to justify invalidating a ballot. That was 20 yrs ago. Any thing more recent?

Comment: I think a better analogy would be showing up to vote, but having to wait in line until after the polls are supposed to close to cast your ballot. So long as you are in line before the deadline, you are still allowed to cast your ballot. Except in this case the ballot has already been cast, it's just the system for counting them that's slow.

Comment: @AquaticFire I think you are misunderstanding, the question has nothing to do with the speed of counting, rather the question has to do with the deadline for ballots to be eligible to be counted.

Comment: If you relax the tone of your post, you might attract fewer DVs and CVs. Right now it sounds like you're asking "Why should we count votes from people dumb enough to turn them in late?"

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I don't mind the down votes, it's the VTC that are frustrating, particularly in light of the accusation that the question is intended to support or discredit a cause, group or politician. In actuality, there are folks who hold that those votes submitted late should be counted (see JCAA below) including the VP candidate in 2000. JCAA contends that SCOTUS approved those types of ballots, and because of precedent that theory persists.  But what I have never seen is a substantive justification  for that practice.

Comment: @BobE It has probably been VTC'd as AtD because you take a really aggressive tone toward such practices. Because Democrats usually try to expand voting rights, and Republicans try to restrict them, your post comes off as an attempt to discredit the Democrats because they're trying to allow people who don't "deserve" to vote because they couldn't follow the deadllines.

Comment: @BobE I edited your question to make it more polite. If you edit in a link to refer to *who* is making the arguments that ballots received after the deadline should be counted, I would upvote and vote to reopen. I have not seen anyone make that argument. Are you referring to some states counting ballots that arrive after but are postmarked on or before Election Day?

Comment: I chose to remove your presumptions, as I think they are relevant to an answer. Feel free to put them back in.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim - I have no problem with your edits, however I will add one tiny parenthetical to make certain that people know which deadline I'm referring to.

Comment: I still don't think it's clear, what submission deadline? Some states have postmarked dates, others have arrived-by dates.

Comment: Not to avoid your question, but one of the issues is states that may use business reply envelopes for the return of the ballot. I'm told that these pre-paid envelopes are not usually post-marked by the post office, so the election officials have no idea when they were submitted. However, logically if the ballot arrives before election day, whether the envelope carries a post-mark or not, it must have been submitted to the post office prior to election day. (continue next)

Comment: OTHO, states that allow ballots to **arrive** after election day seem to universally have requirements that the ballot should have some proof that it was submitted to the PO (by way of a time postmark) prior to the closing of the polls in that state. Now, I can't find the specific complaint in all the lawsuits being tossed around, but the gist of 1 of the arguments is that a voter who uses a business reply envelope supplied by the state, may submit that ballot to the PO well in advance of submission deadline, but due to mail slowdowns it does not arrive at the BOE on or before polls close.

Comment: (continue) So, the argument goes, the voter's ballot is disqualified because it could not proven that it was submitted prior to the poll closing. Ergo, the voter is disenfranchised, through no fault of his own.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim: I wanted to make one final point, are you willing to chat?

Comment: Can you edit this information and a link into the question?

Comment: If you have 'some argue' written in your question, you should really quote and source at least one example.

Comment: @Jontia see https://www.cnn.com/2000/ALLPOLITICS/stories/11/21/overseas.ballots/index.html FL AG Butterworth announced that FL counties **should** count overseas ballots that arrived despite the lack of postmark to establish that ballots had been mailed prior to the deadline for mailing. see https://www.cnn.com/2015/11/02/politics/bush-gore-military-ballots/index.html , to this day (2015) Liberman: "It was not consistent, or right, for us to say, 'Try to find a technical reason to not count an absentee ballot,'.

Comment: @Jonita Much more recently lawsuits are being filed in multiple jurisdictions demanding that  ballots be counted despite late submissions. **I have not been able to locate the text of any of these lawsuits**  - hence my question are there arguments that support the position that ballots that miss the submission deadline should be nontheless counted

Comment: This Q was edited days after it was answered (by Ted: Aug 15 '20 at 19:19; edited Aug 19 '20 at 3:16) to change "received" to "submitted". I'm rolling back to the version that was answered and also voting to delete this Q as it's probably not going to be reopened. Feel free to ask your real Q again, separately, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @Fizz - at this stage I really don't care

Answer (score 3):

I think it's universally accepted that there should be reasonable deadlines for voting; we have to set some (arbitrary) limit that marks off when a submitted vote is acceptable and when it is not. But the key word here is 'reasonable'. In a healthy, functioning democracy we *want* to count votes. We want to make it easy for people to vote; we want to be generous and flexible about problems and issues that might arise; we want to give voters the benefit of the doubt as much as possible in order to ensure that everyone has a reasonable chance to express themselves in their government. Anytime people get bureaucratic and legalistic about it — e.g., one must to do this, by this time, in this place, jumping through these hoops and meeting these restrictions, or else one's vote does not count — they are working in an explicitly anti-democratic mode. They want to make it hard for people's votes to count; they want to be ungenerous and rigid in the hopes that they can round-bin as many votes as possible.

This isn't so much a matter of 'plausible arguments'. One believes in democratic principles or one doesn't, and if one *does* s'he takes voting as an intrinsic, defended right, adopting an expansive, generous attitude towards it, not a constrictive, 'tough luck' attitude. Ample opportunity or not, ample time or not, the *spirit* of democracy calls for openness.

Comment: I'm confused by your answer, On one hand you accept that legal deadlines are universally accepted (in our democracy). They have been accepted for years as being reasonable. OTHO, you propose that enforcing these long standing laws (as being legalistic) is anti-democratic.

Comment: @BobE: I'm sorry I was confusing. The point is that *any* rule can be abused. When a rule is used in such a way that it undercuts the very thing it was meant to protect, then that rule is being abused. The goal is to give every reasonable chance for people to vote; that goal is somewhat more difficult to achieve in the middle of a global pandemic, and the rules should be flexible enough to keep that goal in sight.

Comment: I agree with that sentiment. OTOH, if the regular rules allow for mail voting (for example in Ohio commencing October 6 through November 3) do those rules need to be expanded during a pandemic?  I would propose that the (OH) time period for mail voting is pretty flexible already.  If other states have significantly restricted time period (say less than a week) is perhaps too restrictive - especially in light of efforts or attempts to process and deliver mail. But the corrective measure there ought to be legal action on the cause rather than the effect.

Comment: @BobE: Yeah, I'm not really trying to make any prescriptive claims, except to highlight that distinction between reasonable and unreasonable limits. State governors are going to have to make these assessments on their own, and I'm just hoping they make them well.

Comment: I'd agree with that. However, here's the problem I suspect that they will face: If the voter is provided an opportunity to vote for (say) 30 days, but elects to wait till the last possible moment when the risk is highest that his ballot might not arrive in time, should the rules be changed (after the election) to accommodate the risk-takers. The key issue for election officials becomes  changing the rules of the game AFTER the election for certain players (to accommodate  risk takers)  versus changing the rules BEFORE the election for all players.

Comment: I'd agree with that as well. Especially about fail-points, as well IMO voters also need to attempt to comply with the rules. Abject failure on the part of the voter to take that responsibility seriously should not endow the voter with additional privileges AFTER the fact.

Comment: @BobE: I'm a bit disturbed by your consistent efforts to turn this back on the voter — the people who have the least power and control over this situation — and your constant harping on the image of the *feckless voter*,a s though the biggest problem in our political system right now is all those lazy, stupid citizens. You're trying to spin this so hard I'm surprised you're not making yourself dizzy. Or maybe you are... But in any case, this isn't the place to have this argument, so we should table this.

Comment: Let's consider another possible scenario: Many jurisdictions are providing drop-off boxes to accept ballots this year. Presumably those drop-off boxes will be "shut down" and the ballots removed at a time that is consistent with the end of in-person voting.  Voter "A" tries to deposit his ballot a couple of hours after the end of in-person voting  (perhaps even after early results are being broadcast). His reason for tardiness is that he just got off-work, couldn't make it until after early results were being broadcast.  ---Rational to accept his ballot??

Comment: Ok, let's table.... eventually my position is that various election rules should be changed NOW, to allow voters to enjoy the franchise, Not changed after the fact for selective voters.  As to turning this back to the voter, IMO that there is **shared** responsibility, and voters actually do have considerable power and control about when they choose to vote. So OK, lets table, and thank you for the discussion, I've learned some things from you and others (which I think is the objective of SE - Yes?

Answer (score -4):

It can happen that a ballot mailed a week before election arrives a week after the election because of the USPS problems. In that case the lawyers of both parties will argue that all votes should be counted regardless of when they arrive. The post stamps, by the way, are also not to be trusted (precedent: Dem primaries in NYC).

Comment: You're implying Republican lawyers have argued late received ballots should be counted in the NYC primary. Is this what you intended?